# Client cached and Synch with remote Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, local-storage, breeze, clientcache

I'm trying to sync data between a real MongoDB db on a remote server and a local storage on the client. and I've came across this lib called [Minimongo](https://github.com/mWater/minimongo)
Here is what were aiming for:

were trying to sync small portion of e.g. a document, so that the user can have something to work with while in the client and not been pinging mongo at every moment...

Then if the user closes  the browser and  logs back in have a cached part of the document and be able to connect to mongo to see if the document has change or not. And if that's the case restore it from the remote mongoDB instance.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087958/synchronizing-mongodb-server-data-to-an-indexeddb-local-store) is also relevant and similar for what were trying to achieve

So  how can we proceed with this workflow using minimongo or if there is another lib/tool like it that can aid in this process ?